# How to set the distance widget in android

Tags: android, widget

### How to set distance widget as below in android

I Clearly am able to set the rating bar but the next one i am having trouble in attaining

Is there any solution

[image]

Code i have now ::

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RestaurantPicImageLinearViewID"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: is not very clear what you have to do..

Comment: As seen in the pic .... I have code for rating bar but for the next image (i:e) distance how to step up ? .... hope i am clear

Comment: it seems that you're using a RelativeLayout, so you could just add `android:layout_marginLeft` to the Image

Comment: What i meant was .... what is the code for setting a widget like distance